# How to use custom functions as Django autocomplete_fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

This is my `site/app/models.py`

```
class Country(models.Model):
    class Countries(models.IntegerChoices):
        US = 1, 'United States'
        IND = 2, 'India'
        UK = 4, 'United Kingdom'

    country_name = models.IntegerField(choices=Countries.choices)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nationalities = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

This is my `site/app/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Country, Person


class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['country_name']


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['nationalities']


admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

**Note**: This is minimum sample example which should work. For me similar is working just fine.

**Question**

The problem with above approach is that in searchable fields, `'country_name'` only searches for `integers` (off course). The question is, can I use something like `get_country_name_type_display` to make it more useful?

Comment: why you use class to define choices?

Comment: From docs. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types

Comment: Internally the `country_name` field values are saved as `INTEGER` and hence you can't query like **`.filter(country_name__icontains='india')`**

Comment: I feared that. Thanks. I think, I will have to include full name in the db.